# Turn all colors brightness to 50

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-conversion

I need to edit a picture and convert all single pixels mantaining hue and saturation but changing brightness to 50.
Is there anyone who knows how to achieve this result on Photoshop or with any other tool?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've found the answer.
It was not so immediate, but it works perfectly.
I'll try to illustrate all the steps:

1) Duplicate the original picture and rename it as "copy"
2) Clip to "copy" a new adjustment layer B/W and move the cursor to 100 for all channels
3) Set "copy" blending mode to divide
4) Create a new layer, fill it with 50% grey and set blending mode to multiply

You now have a perfect 50% brightness version of your image.

Answer (score 0):

[image: by these u can Adjust the brightness.........]

or select Hue/saturation in that u can adjust lightness

Comment: This way you're not setting all pixels brightness to 50. You can easily check with eyedropper tool. Anywhere you click you should see a B value of 50% but if you increase or reduce the whole image brightness or luminosity that won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

#### Gimp

To set all pixel values to a fixed brightness value of 50 we may use the *Bucket Fill* tool with fill mode set to *"Value"*. This will replace all brightness values with the value of the foreground color, leaving hue and saturation unchanged. Similar bucket fill settings but presumably with different names will likely exist for other applications too.

- Source:

  [image]
- Value 50 using 50% grey as foreground color:

  [image]

Comment: The result looks more or less like the one I should achieve. I'll try to figure out how to do it in PS, in case it won't work I will install Gimp.
Thanks.

Comment: I believe it is *Paint Bucket - Blend Mode - Luminosity* in PS but cant test this here (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-77eba.html)

Comment: I've already tried it. Unluckily it lightens up dark tones to more or less 50 but light ones keep floating over that value.